# vb.net as I query Access database and display it in listview?

Tags: database, vb.net, listview

I'm creating a form where I can do the following:
[please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/823bh.png) 
 As you can see, I have a **txt_id_up** and **txt_id_dw**
in the database I want to make the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla1
WHERE ID BETWEEN 3 AND 7;
```

where **txt_id_up** = 3, and txt_id_dw = 7;

```
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection
    Dim command As OleDbCommand
    Dim data_reader As OleDbDataReader

    '------------------------------
    'connect to ms.access database
    connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
    Source= data\base.accdb;Persist Security Info=False")
    connection.Open()
    'reading data from Tabla1 table
    command = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Tabla1", connection)
    data_reader = command.ExecuteReader
    '----------------------------------
    'here the code to show in listview1 is missing
    '----------------------------------
```

and in passing I would like to ask another question, can only the following columns be shown in **listview**?
**Name
Account**

I clarify that I use the **datagridview** to see it in general and the **listview for queries**

Comment: Loop through your reader and add ListView items.  As asked, this question is too broad for this site.

Comment: apologies of the case, well the doubt made me ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I get your question but if you want to display **Name** and **Account** from your database I suggest you to use `DataGridView`.

Add a `DataGridView` control to your form and add this code:

```
Dim connection As OleDbConnection
Dim command As OleDbCommand
Dim data_adapter As OleDbDataAdapter

'------------------------------
'connect to ms.access database
connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source= data\base.accdb;Persist Security Info=False")
connection.Open()
'reading data from Tabla1 table
command = New OleDbCommand("SELECT Name, Account FROM Tabla1 WHERE ID BETWEEN 3 AND 7", connection)
data_adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(command)

'add results to DataGridView1
 Dim datatable as New DataTable("Table")
 data_adapter.Fill(datatable)          
 DataGridView1.DataSource = datatable
```

Comment: I have a datagridview and I use it to see it in general, but I want to use a listview to consult

Comment: The query above will only list you Name and Account. But if you want to use ListBox you could loop through the `OleDbDataReader` like LarsTech said.

Comment: hi, in <code> data_adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(command, connection)<code>, I get an error, it can not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

I may have the 2 text boxes backwards.

```
Public Class Form3
    Private Sub FillListView()
        ListView1.BeginUpdate() 'keeps the control from repainting on each addition
        Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
    Source= data\base.accdb;Persist Security Info=False")
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ID, Name FROM Tabla1 Where ID Between ? And ?;", connection)
            command.Parameters.Add("FirstID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(txt_id_up.Text)
            command.Parameters.Add("SecondID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(txt_id_dw.Text)
            connection.Open() 'Open the connection at the last possible minute
            Using data_reader = command.ExecuteReader
              While data_reader.Read()
                Dim li As New ListViewItem()
                li.Text = CStr(data_reader.GetValue(0)) 'ID
                li.SubItems.Add(CStr(data_reader.GetValue(1))) 'Name
                ListView1.Items.Add(li)
              Loop
            End Using
        End Using
        ListView1.EndUpdate()
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Edit**

1. The BeginUpdate of the ListView control prevents the screen from
   repainting every time you add an item. This speeds up the addition
   of items.
2. The Using...End Using block makes sure your connection is closed and disposed 
    event if there is an error.
3. I added question marks in the Where clause of your SQL statement.
   These are placeholders for parameters in the Access/OleDb provider.
4. I added the 2 parameters to the Parameters collection of the Command
   object. The Add method has a number of overloads. The one used here
   takes a name and data type. Then the Value property of the parameter
   is set to the numbers in the text boxes. These values are in a text
   property so they are strings and need the CInt() to convert to
   Integers.
5. I moved the Open method to directly before the command is executed.
6. Again the Using...End Using block as explained above.
7. OOPS! I forgot to add the loop (red face) - Code is now corrected
8. Inside the loop, create a new ListViewItem. A new item for each
   iteration of the loop.
9. Set the Text property of the ListViewItem to the first column in the reader. Convert it to a string. This should show up in the first column.
10. Set the first SubItem of the ListViewItem to the second column of
     the reader. Again convert to a string. This should show up in the
     second column.
11. Add the ListViewItem to the ListView.
12. The first End Using will close and dispose your data_reader. The
     second End Using will close and dispose your connection.
13. Very Important! ListView1.EndUpdate() Nothing shows up in the
     ListView without this line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, can you explain how you did it?